# Что почитать по обеспечению надежности вычислений?

Tags: методы, распараллеливание

Задали такую тему реферата в университете:

Обеспечение надежности вычислений. Понятие надежности. Методы и средства обеспечения надежности вычислений в распределенных вычислительных системах.

К сожалению, гугл не дал ответов на эти вопросы. Равно как и не дали книги Танненбаума, Воеводина и Гергеля. Ну и Косякова, конечно же.
Может, конечно, я плохо смотрел, но там просто нет таких глав или разделов. Везде надежность упоминается вскольз и редко относится именно к вычислениям.

Кто-то может посоветовать, что почитать по этому поводу?
Спасибо.